# BibLateX- Put the shorthand inside quotation marks in the citedas string

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex-chicago` for my paper. Due to I need to cite a lot of legal statutes, I'm using the entry "shorthand" to put an abbreviated form of some acts (EG. Law No. 17.336 on Intelectual Property Rights, hereinafter "IPRA").

The issue is that I want to put the shorthand inside quotation marks "IPRA" only in the first citation and I do not know how to do it.

My first approximation was edit the "citeas" string. In fact I just edited in order to fix the shorthandintro in spanish

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{citedas = {en adelante}}
```

Is this string the one tha I must to modify in order to have quotation marks? (e.g. en adalante "IPRA")

**Edit:** Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@misc{LPC,
address = {},
author = {{Congreso Nacional}},
number = {4},
pages = {1--12},
publisher = {Diario Oficial},
shorthand = {LPC},
title = {{Ley 19.496 sobre Protección a los Derechos de los Consumidores}},
year = {1997}
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{sample}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{citedas = {en adelante}}
\begin{document}
\title{Medios de Pago}
\author{\textsc{Víctor Andrade R}.\thanks{J.D. Universidad de Chile}}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Esto es una prueba

\end{abstract}
\section{Introducción}
Según señala  \autocite{LPC}


\printbibliography[nottype=misc, title =Referencias]
\printbibliography[type=misc,title=Normas Citadas]

\end{document}
```

Greetings,

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  There are quite a number of things that you haven't told us about your document set-up.  Can you provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) demonstrating what you have so far.

Answer (score 2):

With `biblatexte-chicago` the relevant macro is `cms:shorthandintro`.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandintro}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

\renewbibmacro*{cms:shorthandintro}{% For changing the citedas phrase
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}%
  {}%
  {\iffieldundef{shorthandintro}%
    {%\addspace%\setunit{\addspace}% Fix for after postnote field
      \printtext[parens]{%
        \bibstring{citedas}\space%
        \printfield[shorthandintro]{shorthand}}}%
    {%\addspace%\setunit{\addspace}% Ditto
      \printfield{shorthandintro}}}}
```

---

For `biblatex`'s standard styles (such as the `verbose`-family) we need to modify `shorthandintro`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandintro}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

\newbibmacro*{shorthandintro}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthandintro}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
          \bibstring{citedas}\space
          \printfield[shorthandintro]{shorthand}}}}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{\printfield{shorthandintro}}}}
```

Comment: @vandrade If the answer helped you solve your problem, please consider up-voting and accepting it to show that it helped you.